# Finding constant after solving a Differential Equation

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

> Question : $y=f(x)$ is a function that satisfies $$x^2\frac{dy}{dx}=y^2e^\frac{1}{x} \; \text{ and} \;\lim_{x\to  0^-}f(x)=1$$ Find $f(x)$ , given $x\neq0$

Now I solved by dividing both sides by $(xy)^2$ and multiplying by $dx$ we can see that LHS integrates to $\dfrac{-1}{y}$ and we can integrate the RHS to $-e^{1/x}$.
This gives us the required function as $$y=\frac{1}{e^{1/x}-c}$$ (where $c$ is constant of integration.)

But I cannot apply the given limit to find the constant.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure the limit is to $0^+$?

Comment: @Holo My apologies there was a printing mistake in my assignment.Plz check the edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given $$\lim_{x\to0^-}\frac{1}{e^\frac{1}{x}-c}=1$$ we know that $c\ne\lim_{x\to0^-}e^{\frac1x}$. So let's find $\lim_{x\to0^-}e^{\frac1x}$

$\lim_{x\to0^-}e^{\frac1x}=e^{\lim_{x\to0^-}\frac1x}\to e^{-\infty}=0$

So $\lim_{x\to0^-}\frac{1}{e^\frac{1}{x}-c}=\frac1{0-c}=-\frac1c=1\implies c=-1$

Comment: That was easy enough.My apology once again. and thanks.

Comment: @PrakharMishra no need to apologize, everyone can get confused from time to time, this is what exercises are for

Answer (score 0):

The equation can be simplified to
$${dy\over{y^2}}={1\over x^2}e^{1\over x}dx\to e^{1\over x}+C={1\over y}$$
Tending $x\to 0^-$ we get $C={{1\over y(0^-)}}=1$ therefore $f(x)={1\over{e^{1\over x}}+1}$